# get access to running activity in parse push notification custom receiver

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that use parse push notification service. Here is the class that I'm using for receiving notification:

```
public class MessageReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //...some code in here
}
```

And I also register this custom receiver in my manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.package.MessageReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Everything is fine with notification system. After a notification have received, I want to update the running activity UI accordingly (like showing an icon for new notification) but I don't have access to the activity object in `onReceive` method. What is the best practice to do that? I couldn't use the context object in this matter.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this by using a BroadcastReceiver.

You would define the receiver in the activities you want to have access to,
See snippet below.

```
public MyActivity extends Activity
{

    //... code
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //... update ui here
             }
         };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("suitablename"); 
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    //... code
}
```

Then in your custom receiver send the broadcast.

```
public class MessageReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //...some code in here

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("suitablename");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
     }
}
```

Don't forget to update the manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="suitablename"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```